# How to implement this requirement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table
** Table:**

```
MTID     code   boxnumber

1        10-01    10
1        10-02    10
1        10-03    10
1        10-04    10
1        10-05    10
1        11-01    11
1        11-02    11
1        11-03    11
1        11-04    11
1        11-05    11
1        12-01    12
1        12-02    12
1        12-03    12
2        13       NULL
2        14       NULL
2        15       NULL
2        16       NULL
2        17       NULL
2        18       NULL
2        19       NULL
```

Requirement:

In return result, MTID 2 all rows and

MTID 1 conatins full box (count(boxnumber) = 5  where MTID = 1)

In the expected result, code = 12-xx WHERE MTID = 1 not return, because it not full box.

**The Expected Result**

```
MTID     code   boxnumber

1        10-01    10
1        10-02    10
1        10-03    10
1        10-04    10
1        10-05    10
1        11-01    11
1        11-02    11
1        11-03    11
1        11-04    11
1        11-05    11
2        13       NULL
2        14       NULL
2        15       NULL
2        16       NULL
2        17       NULL
2        18       NULL
2        19       NULL
```

Anyone can Help on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `COUNT` as an analytic function here to assert the count of 5 requirement.  Matching rows either belong to `MTID = 1` and having a count of 5 `boxnumber`, or some other value for `MTID`.

```
SELECT MTID, code, boxnumber
FROM
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MTID, boxnumber) cnt
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE (MTID = 1 AND cnt = 5) OR MTID <> 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, @Tim, this is really helpful.